# Is it true that non-equivalent norms share no nontrivial open sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space with two non-equivalent norms $||\cdot ||_1$ and $||\cdot ||_2$. It is clear that they must generate *different* topologies, but I was wandering if it were true that the only open sets they share are $\emptyset$ and $X$.

More specifically (I'm not sure whether or not this is equivalent to what I just asked) I am interested in knowing whether it is true that $B_1(x,r)$ is not $||\cdot ||_2$-open for any $x \in X, r > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_0\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and let $x\in X$. Note then that for any $y\in X$ and any $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and note that $B_r(y)=\frac{r}{r_0}T_{x-\frac{r_0}{r}y}(B_{r_0}(x))$ where $T_m$ is translation by $m$. Since $\frac{r}{r_0}T_{x-\frac{r_0}{r}y}$ is a homeomorphism, this implies that if $B_{r_0}(x)$ is open in any topology then so is $B_r(y)$ for any $r$ and any $y$. Since $\{B_r(y)\}$ is a basis for the topology you could conclude that the two topologies are the same.